# Sum of the first 100 even and odd number?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I need some help getting this code to work. I need the code to calculate the first 100 even and odd numbers. The code below shows the even portion, but I assume they both will work the same way, just with different numbers. I know that the first 100 even numbers are 2 to 200 or 0 to 200?, and the first 100 odd numbers are 1 to 199. (I also need to use while loops, would I use a separate while loop to determine how the code calculate the sum?)

here is the code.

```
    Dim sum, count As Integer 'the sum and count are changing and they must be a whole number. 
    Const num As Integer = 2
    'now we must deveolp a while loop/equation that adds every number lower or equal to 100 together.


    While count Mod 2 <= 200 'while the count is smaller or equal to 100,
        count =
        sum += count 'The sum will be add or equaled to the count
        count += 1 'The count will be added to equaled to 1 

    End While

    Console.WriteLine("The Sum of the first 100 even numbers is: {0}!", sum) 'This is the text the user sees, which tells them that the sum of the first 100 numbers will be 5050.

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

As usual the math portion is giving me trouble. I feel like I have the right idea, but I cant execute it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim sumEven, sumOdd As Integer
    Dim even = 2
    Dim odd = 1

    While even <= 200 AndAlso odd <= 200

        sumEven += even
        sumOdd += odd

        even += 2
        odd += 2

    End While

    Console.WriteLine("The Sum of the first 100 even numbers is: {0}!", sumEven)
    Console.WriteLine("The Sum of the first 100 odd numbers is: {0}!", sumOdd)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works even when I separate the even and odd portions, Thank you!